# What is the purpose of having an option for both role and resource-based policy in Lambda when role inherently has 1 or more policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have created a Lambda function. In the permissions pane there is section for role and another section for resource-based policy.

A role in IAM inherently has a policy. This specifies the resources and actions that the function (via role) has permission to access.

So what is the purpose of having the section for Resource-based policy? If there is access allowed in one and denied in another than which permission is prioritized.

Answer (score 5):

They are two different things.

- The role is *what the lambda can do* (i.e. what the function itself has access to when executing)
- The resource-based policy is *what other principals can do to* the Lambda (i.e. who can execute it, who can update it, who can see it, who can delete it etc)

Lambda is one of a number of services in AWS where this dual set of policies is required as it is both a resource that can be acted upon, and runs as a principal which can act on other things. EC2 Instance Roles are another example.

Comment: Please can you give example of `what lambda can do` and `what other principals can do to the lambda`?

Comment: Lambda can read data from an S3 bucket and an S3 bucket can trigger lambda when certain events occur like the addition of a new object to the bucket.

Answer (score 2):

The IAM role that is attached to the Lambda is used to grant the Lambda the ability to communicate with other AWS resources other the API. If the IAM policy allows access to perform an action, as long as there are no Deny statements the action should be able to be carried out.

The function policy on the other hand is a policy that evaluates invocation of your Lambda function, by default resources within your AWS account can invoke the Lambda should they have the right IAM permissions.

Some services do not have an IAM role that are assigned to them however, so properties such as the Arn of the calling resource or the service that is attempting to invoke the Lambda. In addition you can grant access to another AWS account, or restrict which IAM principals should be able to invoke the function. This is similar to the property of a bucket policy in an S3 bucket.

Comment: How is permission prioritized? For example - A deny in either of them will take priority?

Comment: Explicit deny will always take precedence no matter which authorization mechanism is used within AWS :)

Answer (score 2):

As per the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html).

**Identity-based policies** are attached to an IAM user, group, or role. These policies let you specify what that identity can do (its permissions). For example, you can attach the policy to the IAM user named John, stating that he is allowed to perform the Amazon EC2 RunInstances action. The policy could further state that John is allowed to get items from an Amazon DynamoDB table named MyCompany. You can also allow John to manage his own IAM security credentials. Identity-based policies can be managed or inline.

**Resource-based policies** are attached to a resource. For example, you can attach resource-based policies to Amazon S3 buckets, Amazon SQS queues, and AWS Key Management Service encryption keys. For a list of services that support resource-based policies, see AWS services that work with IAM.

With resource-based policies, you can specify who has access to the resource and what actions they can perform on it. To learn whether principals in accounts outside of your zone of trust (trusted organization or account) have access to assume your roles, see What is IAM Access Analyzer?. Resource-based policies are inline only, not managed.